# Where can I view my tag wiki edits?

Tags: support, tag-wiki

Is there a place in my profile that I can see my tag wiki edits from the past? I know I can find recent ones in my activity log, but what about ones further back?

Comment: http://superuser.com/users/201262/moses?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Answer (score 3):

Sorry if this is a non-SU screenshot, but in the activity tab you can see **all** your suggested edits, being tag wikis, tag excerpt or when you were a non-2K user suggested edits:

[image]

and below you can select all the way back:

[image]

These are not separated of your suggested edits, actually every tag wiki edit counts as suggested edit (and you get 2 rep for that).